# how to insert a new record from asp.net grid view's header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have searched but I got only this:
https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/inserting-a-new-record-from-the-gridview-s-footer-cs

Here footer template is used I want same but data should be inserted from header also the grid view should have a column name as its first row and then textbox as the second row and insert button for every row of the textbox.
Opposite of the solution provided in link.

Comment: Add a table with your requirements and attach it to the top of your gridview. Then simply pass back the textbox values to you database using the insert button. Then refresh your gridview. I personally would not use a gridview. Look into MVC. Here are [examples](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2727/using-webgrid-to-populate-data-as-gridview-in-aspnet-mvc-razorview) of table generation using MVC's Razor Views. Better yet, look into async calls such as those created by AngularJS. This allows you to update your grid display without refreshing the page, while SQL is updated quietly.

Comment: Please, provide reproducible example what result you intend to get and what you've done so far!